# How to avoid modifications during pg_dumpall

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to do a final `pg_dumpall` on a server, then copy the output to a different server and restore the db there.

How can I avoid modification to the database during `pg_dumpall`?

Comment: Just for the records. I solved my use case with this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186051/5705

Answer (score 3):

From the [pg_dump documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) :

> It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used
>   concurrently.

So the backup process takes a snapshot of the DB on a specific moment so each commits which are made during the process are ignored.