# How do I prevent changes to my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, migration, pg-dump

My steps:

1. run the final `pg_dumpall` on a server `prod-server-old`
2. Shut down `prod-server-old` for ever.
3. copy the output to a different server (`prod-server-new`)
4. Restore the db there.
5. All traffic goes to `prod-server-new` now

How can I avoid modification to the database during `pg_dumpall` (between step1 and step2), so that modifications during this time cannot be lost?

In my case it is 100% OK to have a small down time.

There are several databases in the "cluster" (btw, I do not like the word "cluster". I guess most people think a "cluster" is a group of several computers, but in this case it means one Postgres server, which holds several databases).

My question was marked as possible duplicate to "Make Postgres database temporarily read-only (for performing volume snapshots)". I don't think it is a duplicate, since in my case is different since I don't ask for a temporary read-only state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Postgres database temporarily read-only (for performing volume snapshots)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183982/make-postgres-database-temporarily-read-only-for-performing-volume-snapshots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One work-around:

Change the port of PostgreSQL on `prod-server-old`. This way it is unlikely that clients connect to the DB during `pg_dumpall --port=OTHER_PORT`.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to do that:

- If you don't mind about downtime (easy way):

revoke the `connect` privilege to the `public` group. That will prevent everyone but the superusers to connect. Then restart the server or [terminate all connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection), then proceed with the backup using a superuser account.

```
REVOKE CONNECT TO DATABASE (database) FROM public
```

- If you do mind about downtime:

Put your database in read-only mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE (database) SET default_transaction_read_only = true;
```

Proceed with `pg_dumpall`. No restart required and no downtime.

Of course, you have to repeat this on every database you want to "lock". If you have a significative number of databases, you can make the entire cluster read-only: set `default_transaction_read_only = on;` in your postgresql.conf then reload the postgres service.

Please note that I don't have tested any of these commands, proceed at your own risk.

Comment: Note that read-only transactions are only a *default*. An app can simply ask for a read/write transaction. Make sure your app won't do that.

Comment: I thought about this again. Does pg_dumpall dump this readonly state? This would that I need to set the database to write-mode again after I restore the dump on `prod-server-new`. Or do above settings not get dumped by pg_dumpall?

Answer (score 2):

I am a SQL Server admin (not Postgres) so I'm not 100% sure, but if downtime is not an issue can you:

- kill all connections
- prevent remote log ons
- log on to the db server and log into the db as super user
- do the pg_dumpall
- re-enable remote log ons

?

Comment: Please elaborate "prevent remote log ons"

Answer (score 0):

Using triggers:

```
create function __fn_db_readonly() returns event_trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
  raise exception '%', 'Database is in read-only mode';
end $$;

create function _fn_db_readonly() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
  raise exception '%', TG_ARGV[0];
end $$;

create function set_db_readonly(amessage text) returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
  t record;
  tbl_name text;
  stm text;
begin
  if coalesce(amessage, '') = '' then
    -- Database
    drop event trigger __tg_ro_database1;
    drop event trigger __tg_ro_database2;
    drop event trigger __tg_ro_database3;
    -- Data
    for t in (select * from pg_tables where not schemaname in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')) loop
      tbl_name := format('%I.%I', t.schemaname, t.tablename);
      stm := 'drop trigger if exists _tg_ro on ' || tbl_name;
      execute stm;
    end loop;
  else
    -- Data
    for t in (select * from pg_tables where not schemaname in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')) loop
      tbl_name := format('%I.%I', t.schemaname, t.tablename);
      stm := format('create trigger _tg_ro before insert or update or delete on %s execute procedure _fn_db_readonly(%L)', tbl_name, amessage);
      execute stm;
    end loop;
    -- Database
    create event trigger __tg_ro_database1 on ddl_command_start execute procedure __fn_db_readonly();
    create event trigger __tg_ro_database2 on table_rewrite execute procedure __fn_db_readonly();
    create event trigger __tg_ro_database3 on sql_drop execute procedure __fn_db_readonly();
  end if;
  return;
end $$;
```

Then to make database read-only:

```
select set_db_readonly('Database is in read-only mode due to maintance.');
```

and to make it editable again:

```
select set_db_readonly('');
```